# pass function as parameter to dynamically created component blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to pass some parameters to a dynamically generated component

**Parent**

```
...
    DynamicComponent = builder =>
        {
            Type moduleType = Type.GetType(ChildComponentName);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(moduleType);
            if (moduleType != null)
            {
                builder.OpenComponent(0, moduleType);
                builder.AddAttribute(1, "title", "Delete + " + item.Name + "?");
                builder.AddAttribute(2, "content", "Are you sure you want to delete this organization?");
                builder.AddAttribute(3, "YesCallback", whatgoeshere?);
                builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(1, inst => { child = Convert.ChangeType(inst, moduleType); });
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }
        };

    public void Delete(string msg)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
            items.RemoveAt(DeleteIndex);
        }
...
```

**Child**

```
...
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Content { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> YesCallback { get; set; }
...
```

The component get's generated and displayed fine. The first two parameter are set fine. What I can't figure out is how to pass the parent `Delete` function as third attribute so the child can call it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `EventCallbackFactory.Create` to create event callbacks from simple actions. Along with the action you have to pass the event receiver which is usually the component on which the action is being executed.

You can access the factory through `EventCallback.Factory`:

```
var callback = EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, arg =>
{
    // do something
});
```

You can also pass a method with the correct signature instead:

```
var callback = EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, OnCallback);
```

You can then pass the created event callback directly to the `AddAttribute` method:

```
builder.OpenComponent(0, componentType);
builder.AddAttribute(1, "OnSomething", callback);
builder.CloseComponent();
```

Comment: in NET 6 is litle change  -- EventCallback callback = new EventCallbackFactory().Create<string>(this, SomeMethodOrTask);

Comment: @areklipno .NET 6 still has [`EventCallback.Factory`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v6.0.5/src/Components/Components/src/EventCallback.cs#L14-L17) which you can use to avoid having to create new factory instances over and over again.

Comment: yes but Create method is not static and you need new instance: new EventCallbackFactory().Create instead of EventCallbackFaktory.Create. Result is the same.

Comment: @areklipno `EventCallback.Factory` is static though and points to a shared instance of `EventCallbackFactory` on which you can use the (non-static) `Create` method.

Comment: sory - my mistake... I have not seen this dot before...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> Click { get; set; }

public async Task OnClickCallback(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    await Click.InvokeAsync(e);
}

protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
    var seq = 0;
    builder.OpenElement(seq++, "li");
    builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, OnClickCallback));
    builder.CloseElement();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 2 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.